# React Props undefined in state (inside of constructor) only available in render method

Tags: reactjs

I've been wracking my brain trying to figure out why I can't set the state with my this.props

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  BrowserRouter, 
  Route,
  Switch,
  NavLink,
  withRouter
 } from "react-router-dom";
 import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
 import DatePicker from "./DatePicker.js";

class BasicEditInfoTag extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  console.log(this.props);
  this.state = {
   tag: "",
   tagName: "",
  };
}

}
render(){
 <div className='tag_name_tag'>
  <label>Name of Tag</label>
  <i className="fas fa-tags"></i>
  <input type='text' name='name_tag' className='name_tag' ref={this.input} placeholder="Enter tag name" value={this.props.tagData.tag_name} onChange={this.handleInputChange.bind(this)} />
  {this.props.tagData.tag_name}
```

}

As you can see the first console.log returns empty array.
but once inside the render method my data array is available.
I need to set the state so i can set input values for my form.

Comment: Please do not include images of code... format and post the code here...

Answer (score 0):

1. State mutations are not recommended in constructor. It’s not the place for state mutations
2. The way you are mutating state tagName is not recommended. Direct state mutations won’t trigger re-render so you won’t see updated data in the screen if you do direct mutation

Remove below line of code from constructor and in render as well

```
   this.state.tagName = this.props.tagData.tag_name;
```

I could see the only issue is above Line in your code otherwise everything looks fine in your code. After removing give a try it should work as expected

Update:

```
  Remove that line of code wherever you used in your component
```

Comment: Fair enough, Im trying to render my input fields with values from my data array. but the values have to be set in the state, Otherwise I get the component is changing the uncontrolled input type warning.

Comment: @wisert further assistance please share complete component code instead of pieces

Comment: @wisert to fix the warning you need to remove that line of code in render as well and if you are doing that in other places remove there as well

Comment: new constructor `  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      console.log(this.props);
      this.state = {
       tag: "",
       tagName: "",
    };
  }
`

Comment: ` <div className='tag_name_tag'>
      <label>Name of Tag</label>
      <i className="fas fa-tags"></i>
      <input type='text' name='name_tag' className='name_tag' ref={this.input} placeholder="Enter tag name" ref={this.input} value={this.props.tagData.tag_name} onChange={this.handleInputChange.bind(this)} />
      {this.props.tagData.tag_name}
   </div>`

Comment: @wisert please be clear and cleaner. Who’s stopping you to add the complete component code in the question instead of comments?